# Can't replace file names with PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have files like this.

```
[mix]aaaa.flv
[mix]aaaa.mpv
[mix]aaaa.ogv
[mix]aaaa.webm
[mix]bb.flv
[mix]bb.mpv
[mix]bb.ogv
[mix]bb.webm
...
```

I just need to remove "`[mix]`" from the file names.

I use this command, but failed

`Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "[mix]", "" }`

Error says

```
Rename-Item : 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Desktop\[mix]aaaa.mp4'에 항목이 없으므로 이름을 바꿀 수 없습니다.
위치 줄:1 문자:18
+ Dir | Rename-Item <<<<  –NewName { $_.name –replace “[mix]“,”” }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

There's korean in error code, it might say : `Can't change name, there is no item at 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Desktop\[mix]aaaa.mp4'`

And I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I used to change file names with this command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a known bug with Rename-Item and powershell 2.0

What I did was to use Move-Item instead, you should be able to use the following (tested on powershell 2.0):

```
Dir | Move-Item -Destination {$_.Name -replace "\[mix\]", ""}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make this work. Remember that `[` and `]` are regex metacharacters and need to be escaped:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "\[mix\]",""}
```

Comment: Still same result. It seems PowerShell can't find the files. But using `dir` command, I can see a list of files. what's going on here..

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5477, 
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514

Comment: If you're looking at `$PSVersionTable` what is the value of `PSVersion`?  I tried this on PowerShell 4.0 and it works.

Comment: My `PSVersion` is `2.0`.

Comment: I think the David is right.  Rename-Item works on V4 (probably V3 as well) but definitely does not work in this scenario on V2.  The wildcard chars throw it off.  Use Move-Item as he suggests.  I've verified that works on V2.